# how to calculate multiple elements sum and average with RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, databricks-community-edition

I am a big newbie in pyspark. have organized a RDD with the following code:

```
rdd1 = labRDD.map(lambda kv: (kv[0].split("/")[-1].split('.')[0], kv[1]))
rdd2 = rdd1.flatMapValues(lambda v: v.split('\r\n'))
rdd3 = rdd2.map(lambda kv: (kv[0], kv[0].split('_')[0], kv[1].split()[0], int(kv[1].split()[1])))
```

The result is ('town','shop','month','revenue') :

```
[('anger', 'anger', 'JAN', 13),
 ('marseille', 'marseille_1', 'FEB', 12),
 ('marseille', 'marseille_2', 'MAR', 14),
 ('paris', 'paris_1', 'APR', 15),...]
```

I **am forced** not to use dataframe, thus I need RDD results.
I have to calculate :

- Average monthly income of the shop (all branches/stores) in France
- Average monthly income of the shop (all branches) in each city
- Total revenue per city per year
- Total revenue per store per year
- The store that achieves the best performance in each month

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer to the two first ones :)

Total revenue per city per year

```
annual_city_rev = rdd3.map(lambda t:(t[1], t[3])).reduceByKey(lambda x,y:int(x)+int(y))
annual_city_rev.collect()
```

Total revenue per store per year

```
annual_store_revenue = rdd3.map(lambda t:(t[0], t[3])).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: int(x)+int(y))
annual_store_revenue.collect()
```